# HttpWebRequest+Exception=How do i get header/body?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, webclient

I'm trying to debug an exception that happens once in a blue moon with HttpWebRequest. However, i have no idea how to get the body nor header. I saw an answer on SO but it was clearly incorrect as you cant cast the exception to the class he was thinking of.

I tried grabbing the response stream and got a verb error. I googled "msdn httpwebrequest exception get headers" but it mostly talks about headers in the httpwebrequest and list possible exceptions... not what i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a `WebException`, you can get the response from that using [`WebException.Response`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx). It's not clear what exception you've actually got though, or whether this is the answer you've already seen elsewhere... if this doesn't help you, please give more information.